# Django-admin: after-save callback for inline forms

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Here is a Django -dmin problem.
A **ModelAdmin** class contain inlines (basically this is User as main admin form and UserProfile as its inline form).
I need to call a code after this UserProfile inline has been saved.

That goal is to check if newly saved inline has field "something"=1 and execute my code.
For User model this would be **save_model()** that I would need to override to add my lines.

Question:
How does one call code after inline form has been saved?
What's the "save_model()" for inline models?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use `save_related()` method:

```
def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
    """
    Given the ``HttpRequest``, the parent ``ModelForm`` instance, the
    list of inline formsets and a boolean value based on whether the
    parent is being added or changed, save the related objects to the
    database. Note that at this point save_form() and save_model() have
    already been called.
    """
    form.save_m2m()
    for formset in formsets:
        self.save_formset(request, form, formset, change=change)
```

You can incorporate some logic here based on `formset` class.
Or you can use `save_formset()` method directly.

Comment: I think InlineModelAdmin inherits from BaseModelAdmin that does not have this method.

Comment: You are right. I found another method on `ModelAdmin`: `save_related`